# cv2.imshow and cv2.imwrite produce different images from same source

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, imaging

I am creating an image from a NumPy array which was created by a style transfer net.

```
output = net.forward()
```

The output is the renormalized from the net processing:

```
output = output.reshape((3, output.shape[2], output.shape[3]))
output[0] += 103.939
output[1] += 116.779
output[2] += 123.680
output /= 255.0
output = output.transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

When I display this with `cv2.imshow`, I get the correct image. Now I try and convert this to an image file for saving and display; first I rescale the image back up to the 0 - 255 integer range with:

```
output = (output * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

Then save it with:

```
cv2.imwrite(path + "/" + "Test_Out" + '.jpg', output)
```

The latter image has color artifacts that I can't explain. (I don't have enough reputation to display the images.)

Any ideas how to properly display the NumPy array?

Comment: Paste the link to image here and some one would help you with displaying.

Comment: Maybe your net is producing an RGB image whereas OpenCV is expecting a BGR image. So if your reds and blues are swapped, change your saving code to `cv2.imwrite(path,output[...,::-1])`

Answer (score 2):

My wild guess is that

1. `output*255` is not entirely the same with the float valued `output`
2. `jpg` is lossy format, so some artifacts is normal.

You can try:

1. `output = np.clip(output*256,0, 255)`
2. save with `.png` extension/format